# Markov property of the Brownian motion

Tags: brownian-motion, markov-process, stopping-times

For the Brownian motion $B$ on the probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ with filtration $\mathcal{F}_n = \sigma(B_s,s\leq n)$ for $t\geq0$ and for any stopping time regarding $(\mathcal{F}_n)_{n\geq0}$ is $\tilde{B}:=B_{n+\tau}-B_{\tau}, t\geq 0$ a Brownian motion, which is independent of $\mathcal{F}_{\tau}$.

Let $(B_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of iid random variables with $\mathbb{P}(B_n = 1)=p$ and $\mathbb{P}(B_n=-1)=1-p$. We look at the simple random walk $S_n:=B_1+\dots+B_n$.

How can I use the strong Markov property to prove $(B_{n+\tau}-B_{\tau})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is independent of $\mathcal{F}_{\tau}$?

Comment: Is your question about $\Delta B$ or $\Delta S$?

Comment: @ECL My question is about $\Delta B$.

Comment: So why are you adding somuch unnecessary information? First you define a Brownian motion and you call it $B$ (I guess you mean a continuous time process). Then you redefine $B$ as a discrete sequence of independent variables. Then you define $S$ as partial sum of this sequence. Then you ask about $\Delta B$. Why not stating the question in 2 lines only? Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: Anyway, $B_{n+\tau}-B_\tau$ is not independent of $\mathcal{F}_\tau$. But $S_{n+\tau}-S_\tau$ is.

Comment: @ECL Sorry, maybe I mixed up something. Now I have edited the question, does it make sense now?